# PHP: Access return value from function of class after require_once

Tags: php, function, class, return-value, require

```
class DB{
  function potatoe(){
  ... a lot of code ...
  return array('x'=>nothing, 'y'=>something, 'z'=>anything);
  }
}
```

Then require_once is used in a separate file:

```
require_once __dir__."/DB.php";
$object = new DB();
$object->potatoe();
```

But the object remains empty. I am unable to access the return value of the class. The variables have values, I have checked this with var_dump.

edit:

```
if($object->potatoe()){
    echo "test";
}
else{
    echo "nichts";
```

returns true ...

Comment: What? What is your question?

Comment: Enable error reporting and put a `var_dump` around the `potatoe` call.

Comment: A singular is called a `potato` without the `e`.

Comment: classes don't have "return values". instantiating an object "returns" an instance of that class, but it's not a return value of anything. it's just a reference/pointer to wherever this new instance of the class exists in memory.

Comment: Seriously, I have tried so many things that I did not check for a var_dump around the entire call. I had been there all along. The only thing that I have to do now is to extract those three arrays out of the object and into another function. Thanks so far

Comment: Do this way `$temp=$object->potatoe(); print_r($temp);` and tell what it is printing

Answer (score 0):

The method returns a value but you aren't assigning that value to anything.
`$object->potatoe();` calls the method but it doesn't store the return anywhere for you to access it. If you did `$foo = $object->potatoe();` then you should be able to access your array as `$foo`. If you wanted to access it directly as a property you would want to do `$object->propertyName = $object->potatoe();` but that feels a touch silly to me, if I knew the array I needed I would just assign it to the property statically to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have also posted a comment asking about this.

```
require_once __dir__."/DB.php";
$object = new DB();
$temp=$object->potatoe(); 
print_r($temp);
```